# How to ignore all letters and characters and just the number zero?

Tags: regex

I have the following code:

```
onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')
```

It is possible to ignore all characters other than numbers [0-9]. However, I need zero at the beginning to be ignored too, but only at the beginning of a number. I would like the code to be added to solve my problem, that is, keep the code "in line" so that I can add it to the HTML TAG later.

The new code should output the values of the following examples:

Input:

```
025
000013
103
250007
```

Output:

```
25
13
103
250007
```

Comment: You could add another `replace` after the first: `.replace(/^0*/), '')`. If you need the input '0' to produce '0' though you would need something like `.replace(/^(0(?!$))*/, '')`.

Comment: Thank you friend. I did so and it worked as expected: `onkeyup="if (/\D|0/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D|^0*/g, '')"`

Comment: Glad I could help. Just beware that by combining the two with the pipe in the way that you have, 'A025' will become '025' rather than '25' as I expect you may prefer.